# How can I turn this off? VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[My VS Code screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmJU0.jpg)
How can I turn this off I wonder it's too distracting.

Comment: There's probably a documentation-finding plugin that can be toggled in the settings. It may be a good idea to just get used to that popup though. It's common in many IDEs, and is extremely helpful when working with code written by someone else (and even code written by you in larger projects).

Comment: Thank you,have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage keeping this enabled, because it's very useful. However, I can appreciate that after a lot of experience it could become a bit pointless.

You can enable/disable that pop up by going to `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > Type in `parameter hints` and then you'll see this:

[image]